# style attribute convert number decimal in french notation

Tags: reactjs

I try to put inline style in ReactJS like this :

```
<div style={{width: '15.5%'}}></div>
```

And the rendering DOM is

```
<div style="width: 15,5%"></div>
```

Yes with a **,** and not a **.**

Have you any ideas why? And how fix this stuff?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok
I have this probleme only on electron ( In Chrome/Firefox, no soucy )
And on electron, I have a invalid property in dev tool, but width with "," works.

I close this issue. Thank you for replying.

Answer (score 0):

Something in your code because react convert work correctly

This is code work `<div style={{width: '15.5%',background: 'red'}}`

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/71469/